# Is it possible to generate an .apk from an Espresso test project

Tags: android, shell, automation, adb, android-espresso

I am fairly new to android development, so please be patient.

I want to create an automated test for an application and run it via adb
The test case that I generated does simple actions (such as clicking buttons)
however I can't find a way to simply run this test without having to use Android studio

```
   @Test
    public void mainActivityTest() {
        ViewInteraction switch_ = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.switch1), withText("Switch"), isDisplayed()));
        switch_.perform(click());
```

Is there a way to take the package generated by espresso and run it directly from adb, without having to open the source code and android studio (since it takes a lot of resources ) ?

If not, is there some kind of independent automation tool that would generate a test file and that test would be ran from an ADB shell.

Answer (score 1):

You can run instrumentation tests [from the command line](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/command-line.html) using Gradle tasks (e.g., `connectedAndroidTest`).

Comment: So after generating the a testcase, will I be able to run said testcase without the need to open android studio at all ?

Comment: Is it possible to run the testcase without the source code

Comment: @Flash10101: "So after generating the a testcase, will I be able to run said testcase without the need to open android studio at all ?" -- yes. "Is it possible to run the testcase without the source code" -- no.